# web3-core-method.umd.js:1191 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, react

Keep getting this error and really not sure what's causing it.

Smart contract:

```solidity
contract BasaltStore {
  // struct of how a document will be stored
  struct documentStore {
    // unique id of the doc
    uint256 id;
    // the url of the ipfs node where the document is stored
    string ipfsHash;
    // wallet address of who uploaded the document
    address uploader;
    // date the document was uploaded (created here)
    uint dateUploaded;
  }

  // mapping of all documents
  mapping (uint64 => documentStore) public ListOfDocuments; 
  // count of all documents stored
  uint256 public documentCount;

  /** Stores the newly created document details */
  function sendDocument(
    string memory _ipfsLocation, 
    uint256 _uploadDate,
    uint64 _key
  ) 
  public
  {
    documentCount ++;
    ListOfDocuments[_key] = documentStore(documentCount, _ipfsLocation, msg.sender, _uploadDate);
  }

  /** Retrieves docuement details */
  function getDocument(
    uint64 _id
  ) 
  public 
  view
  returns (string memory, address, uint256)
  {
    // return the attributes of the documentStore we need
    string memory ipfsHash = ListOfDocuments[_id].ipfsHash;
    address uploader = ListOfDocuments[_id].uploader;
    uint256 dateUploaded = ListOfDocuments[_id].dateUploaded;
    return (ipfsHash, uploader, dateUploaded);
  }
}
```

React code calling smart contract:

```js
var key = this.state.StudentNumber + this.state.account[0]
key = parseInt(hash(key), 10)
this.setState({idForBlockchain: key})
console.log(key)

//get todays date
let newDate = new Date()
newDate = newDate.getTime()
var _ipfsLink = this.state.IPFSlink
var _account = this.state.account[0]

await storehash.methods.sendDocument(_ipfsLink, newDate, key).send({from: _account})

//call the smart contract method to create a new document
//storehash.methods.sendDocument(this.state.IPFSlink, newDate).send({from: this.state.account})
console.log("adding student")
await this.createStudent(e)
console.log("student added")
```

It seems to fail after calling the

```js
await storehash.methods.sendDocument(_ipfsLink, newDate, key).send({from: _account})
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: You need to check transaction receipt.  Probably your transaction didn't fail, but just consumed exactly the amount of gas you allowed it to consume.  There is a [bug](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2441) in old versions of Web3js that may cause such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use await calls inside of an async function. Otherwise you will end up having a promise/resolve error.For example, try wrapping the await call inside an async function and call it immediately  after..just to try it out. Like this:

```
var key = this.state.StudentNumber + this.state.account[0]
    key = parseInt(hash(key), 10)
    this.setState({idForBlockchain: key})
    console.log(key)

    //get todays date
    let newDate = new Date()


     newDate = newDate.getTime()
        var _ipfsLink = this.state.IPFSlink
        var _account = this.state.account[0]




  const test =async () => {

            await storehash.methods.sendDocument(_ipfsLink, newDate, key).s

end({from: _account})
        };

test();
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've shown that it's running inside an async function so do you think that's still the issue?